# How can I get other apps' information on a windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone

everyone. Is there a way that I can get some other app's information on a windows phone? This is maybe a silly question, but I'm not familiar with Windows phone platform. Any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the answer here:[How can I get installed apps list in Windows Phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980462/how-can-i-get-installed-apps-list-in-windows-phone)
It seems I asked for a restricted capability and I'm not a partner of Microsoft,pity. Thanks thoungh.